# Applying a shrinkwrapped image to a rigged character

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I have created a character that I needed to put a logo on the front of his shirt. To do that, I used the Shrink Wrap Modifier. This worked fine, but now that I have built a rig for the character and am moving him , the logo does not move with the character. Is there something I can do to change this? is there a way to make the logo move with the rest of the shirt?

Comment: This is the first time I see a shrik wrap as a logo texture(good idea). But... Try to click in the shrinkWrap object, then Shif click on the object and Ctrl + p>>object. This will make the logo follow the object. It worked to me. If it works to you, tell me to post itas an answer

Comment: I have the shrink wrap object as a child of the body, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I was thinking to parent it to a bone, but i wont get the same movement the shirt gets.

Comment: Ok. The best way to put the logo is using it as a texture.

Comment: Don't use shrinkwrap, use the logo as a texture that is part of the material for the shirt. For cycles see this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material